# Name of a descriptive text field?

Tags: database-design

I have seen descriptive text field named as `DESCRIPTION`, `REMARK`, and `NOTE`. They seem to mean the same thing. So what is more appropriate than the others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A description describes an object like a product.

> Description: 5x10" widget used for squiggle placement.

A remark is often printed on invoices/statements/payments to show to the customer or supplier.

> Remark: This payment relates to invoices #1, #2, and #4.

A note calls out attention to something out of the ordinary or seperate to everything else. It may be internal-only.

> Note: Do not sell any more widgets to this customer because they have an outstanding invoice.

These aren't hard and fast rules but it's where I've seen them used.